# How to replace a character in text file using C?

Tags: c, file, fopen

I need to read a text file (E3-5.txt), and search for character c1 to be replaced by c2.
This is my incomplete code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char c1 = 'm';
    char c2 = 'a';
    int i;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\E3-5.txt", "r+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found!");
        return 0;
    }
    for(c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
    {
        if(c == 'm')
        {
            i = ftell(fp);
            printf("\nPosition %d", i);
        }

    }
}
```

I am having trouble how to locate the position of c1 in the text and how to rewrite it.
Edit:
I used the code from the answer, but it didn't change the text.
This is the new code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char c1 = 'm';
    char c2 = 'a';
    int i;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\E3-5.txt", "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found!");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp))
        {
            if(c == c1)
            {
                fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                fputc(c2, fp);
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

The program returned 0 without writing anything in the text

Comment: as it is windows open with `rb+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getc()` returns an `int` so you need to declare `int c` not `char c` to check for the EOF.

`ftell()` gets the location. Use `fwrite()` or `fputc()` to write to file at that location by setting with `fseek()`.

Go to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c for reference. Lots of beginners fail to read all of the standard library functions, and some even reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, as I used ```char c``` several time in my previous code, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: That's abusing undefined behavior.

Comment: @MariaMarchellaGandhi so you have made the same mistake many times in the past. Learn about undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a very naive one:

```
int freplace(FILE *f, char needle, char repl)
{
    int result = 1;
    int c;
    if(f)
    {
        while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
        {
            if(c == needle)
            {
                fseek(f, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                fputc(repl, f);
                //all I/O functions require error handling
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

## String replace

Just for completeness, here is a bit of code to replace a word in a file! This will replace a single character, so of course it answers the question and shows some useful examples.

*This is also my first and only non-trivial golden program, written in May 1994! Although you can certainly find fault with it, it worked as intended and my co-workers and I used it many different ways for sysadmin-related tasks. Compiled on MS C/C++*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define err(e) {_fcloseall(); fprintf(stderr,        \
           "USAGE: chg source dest oldstr newstr\n%s\n",e); exit(1);}

main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in,*out;
    char buffer[200];
    char *old,*new;
    int i,j,k;


    if (argc!=5)
        err("invalid # of parameters");
    if ((in=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
        err("Can't open source");
    if ((out=fopen(argv[2],"w"))==NULL)
        err("Can't open dest");
    old=argv[3];
    new=argv[4];
    if (*old=='"')
        old++;
    if (*new=='"')
        new++;
    if (i=strlen(old) && old[i-1]=='"')
        old[i-1]=0;
    if (i=strlen(new) && new[i-1]=='"')
        new[i-1]=0;
    if (!*old)
        err("Can't search for nothing!");
    if (!*new)
        err("Can't replace nothing!");
    j=0;
    while (!feof(in))
    {
        if ((buffer[j]=fgetc(in))==EOF)
            break;
        buffer[j+1]=0;
        j++;
        if (!old[j-1])
        {
            fprintf(out,new);
            fputc(buffer[j-1],out);
            j=0;
        }
        else if (_strnicmp(buffer,old,j))
        {
            fprintf(out,buffer);
            j=0;
        }
        else if (j>195)
            err("Internal error, buffer filled past 195");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You really don't want to directly manipulate a file.  Ever.  Doing so is just asking for data corruption.  Instead, create a new file and move it when you're done.  Also, it's a lot easier to write the code.  You can do so with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c1 = argc > 1 ? argv[1][0] : 'm';
    int c2 = argc > 2 ? argv[2][0] : 'a';
    const char *path = argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "stdin";
    FILE *in = argc > 3 ? fopen(path, "r") : stdin;
    if( in == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *out = stdout;
    char tmp[1024] = ".tmpXXXXX";
    char *outpath = "stdout";
    if( argc > 3 ){
        outpath = tmp;
        int fd = mkstemp(tmp);
        if( fd == -1 ){
            perror("mkstemp");
            return 1;
        }
        if( (out = fdopen(fd, "w")) == NULL ){
            perror(tmp);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    int c;
    while( (c = fgetc(in)) != EOF ){
        if( c == c1 ){
            c = c2;
        }
        if( fputc(c, out) == EOF ){
            perror(outpath);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if( argc > 3 ){
        if( fclose(out) ){
            perror(outpath);
            return 1;
        }
        if( rename(outpath, path) ){
            perror(path);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```